# Why is `next` not listed as a method of the `Enumerator` class?

Tags: ruby, methods

The following methods are listed on the documentation page for the [`Enumerator` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html):

- `::new`
- `#each`
- `#each_with_index`
- `#each_with_object`
- `#feed`
- `#inspect`
- `#next`
- `#next_values`
- `#peek`
- `#peek_values`
- `#rewind`
- `#size`
- `#with_index`
- `#with_object`

However when I do the following in `irb` I receive `false`:

```
>> Enumerator.methods.include?(:next)
false
```

Is this because even though the method can be used on instances of this class, the method isn't explicitly defined on the class itself, i.e. it is inherited? Having thought this I also checked `Enumerator` superclasses and found that they do not contain this method either:

```
>> Enumerator.superclass.methods.include?(:next)
false
>> Enumerator.superclass.superclass.methods.include?(:next)
false
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something quite fundamental..

Comment: BTW, `methods` works on enumerator instances the way you expect, e.g. `1.step.methods.include?(:next)` returns `true`. Calling `methods` on the class itself returns, well, class methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#next` is an instance method of the Enumerator class. Using `Enumerator.instance_methods.include?(:next)` will return `true`

Comment: Additionally, `#instance_methods` looks for the methods in the ancestor chain, unless you provide the optional parameter of `false`

https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/instance_methods

Comment: seeker, if you wish to use `methods` rather than `instance_methods`, invoke it on an instance of `Enumerator`, such as `enum = [1,2,3].each #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>`: `enum.methods.include?(:next) #=> true`.

Comment: Simlarly, `Integer.instance_methods.include?(:+) #=> true` and `42.methods.include?(:+) #=> true`. Further to @Rupert's point, here is an example of how one can find *where* in the ancestor chain a method is defined: `Integer.instance_method(:zero?).owner #=> Numeric` (or `42.method(:zero?).owner #=> Numeric`).